# Where should I go for clarification on spam interaction?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Just now I marked an email as "unwanted" in Hotmail and immediately afterwards I received another email from that same domain asking me if I'm sure that their emails are unwanted.

What site should I use to ask for details on how they knew their email was considered unwanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me this is a typical web app user question. Therefore [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) seems the best site to ask this.

From their [help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application

And Hotmail, or Outlook, *is* a web application after all.

Comment: (I guess the answer is: since Microsoft sends a 'newsletter unsubscribe' mail to the sender of the email)