# Which site can I ask about blocking a certain kind of email spam?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have been getting, since a couple of weeks ago, a very strange kind of spam which my mail host cannot block. On which site can I ask about finding a way to block it?

All the spam mails I get have a huge block of Wikipedia quotes from random articles, which means that a large part of each spam mail is unique.

I want to know the right site to ask about finding a way to block this kind of spam.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Where should I go for clarification on spam interaction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267006) and [Where to ask a question about outlook.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306728)

Comment: Obligatory link to how [voting is different on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). To be more specific - I've noticed that people seem to downvote on-topic [site-recommendation] questions when they think the question being asked about is poor in general and/or unfit for SE entirely. For example, the proposed question seems to not be in line with the SE ideal - typically, we're not places to "start researching" or "discuss" topics (both pretty open-ended requests), but instead places to ask specific, focused questions.

Comment: @bobble thank you for this downvote hint makes sense now. Well let's rephrase it: How can I get rid of that kind of spam.

Comment: I think narrowing it to the tech sites first and then scanning the [list view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-oldest) would be a better way to start. Pick two or three that look like they might work and then ask here if none of them are an obvious good fit. But you also might have gotten down votes for not including more information about what type of answers you're looking for. Code, email rules, other? You gave Server Fault as an example but I would have guessed Super User.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No site within the Stack Exchange network will take the (paraphrased) question

> Find a way to block a very strange kind of spam?

There is simply not enough information to start answering that, let alone suggesting a site.

Here are your options, if you can narrow down what you actually need.

- If you are looking for how to configure spam filter options in your locally installed e-mail client, research on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
- If you are looking for configuring spam filter options offered via a Web Application / Saas, research on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- If you are looking for adding spam filters in your self-hosted e-mail server, research on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)
- If you are looking for a plugin to add to your email-client, research on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- If you are looking for ways to legally stop the spam, research on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- If you want to help fight weird spam posted on the Stack Exchange Network, go to [CharcoalHQ](https://charcoal-se.org/about)

None of the sites will take your question in its current form. That is why I stated *research* in all above suggestions. The minimal research is going over their *on-topic* page and related material. If you rather discuss the spam and your options, find a chatroom, reddit or Quora. For venting about spam, use Twitter.